# .NET 5 AspNetCore catch-all route supersedes defined route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

Migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5, we encountered peculiar behavior with a catch-all route configuration.

The relevant part of the startup configuration looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "home",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

        //catch-all endpoint
        endpoints.Map("{*.}", async (t) =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("hello");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    });
}
```

Calling the url: [http://localhost:port/home](https://localhost:port/home) hits the catch-all route instead of the home controller. If the catch-all endpoint map is commented out, the home controller endpoint is hit - which is what we would expect in both cases, reading the MSDN docs. The bahavior before migration was the most specific route called first (i.e. the home controller endpoint), and the catch-all only responded when no route could be matched.

Were there breaking changes in .NET 5, or are we missing something?

Comment: Why are you defining your routes like this instead of using the Route attribute on the controllers?

Comment: This is an oversimplified reproducible example of the question: why does the catch-all route take precedence over the defined route? In reality this is part of a large scale distributed application, where much of the code depends on dynamic routing, which of course fails because of this. What I want to know is if this is the expected behavior, and if such, can it be overridden?

Comment: After a trip through the .NET 5 source led by a third party, it appears that the priority assigning algorithm is faulty - initially, it assigns the home route precedence 0 and the catch-all route precedence 5 due to a hardcoded catch-all if statement. It then sorts the routes by precedence and assigns scores, giving the home route score 1 and catch-all a score of 0. Finally, it sorts scores lower to higher, giving the catch-all ultimate precedence over anything else. Can someone else please confirm this is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the behavior was due to the aspnetcore team introducing a change to the routing mechanism in 5.0 - the problematic behavior is actually by design.

See more here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29594

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use priority to resolve the mismatch. This route can pick up any URL that has not been handled by any other route.

   ```
   [Route("{*url}", Order = 999)]
   public IActionResult CatchAll()
   {

      return View();
   }
   ```
2. In this situation, another method is to use Status Code Pages.

   In startup

   ```
            app.UseExceptionHandler(option=>
            {
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
            });
   ```

   Controller

   ```
    [Route("error/404")]
    public IActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View();
    }
   ```

Comment: Sorry, @Karney, your answer did not answer my question. See accepted answer for more details.